# How to download a zip file from a github repo using libcurl?

Tags: c++, windows, curl, libcurl

I have upload a `zip` file compressed with WinRAR containing a txt file into my github test [Repo](https://github.com/R3uan3/test/releases/tag/test), how I could download the `zip` file using `curl`?

I tried:

```
    static size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
    {
      size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, (FILE *)stream);
      return written;
    }
    
    void Download(std::string url)
    {
      CURL *curl_handle;
      static const char *pagefilename = "data.zip";
      FILE *pagefile;
    
      curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    
      /* init the curl session */ 
      curl_handle = curl_easy_init();
    
      /* set URL to get here */ 
      curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
    
      /* Switch on full protocol/debug output while testing */ 
      curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
    
      /* disable progress meter, set to 0L to enable and disable debug output */ 
      curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);
    
      /* send all data to this function  */ 
      curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
    
      /* open the file */ 
      pagefile = fopen(pagefilename, "wb");
      if(pagefile) {
    
        /* write the page body to this file handle */ 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, pagefile);
    
        /* get it! */ 
        CURLCode res;
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);
    
        /* close the header file */ 
        fclose(pagefile);
      }
    
      /* cleanup curl stuff */ 
      curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);
    
      curl_global_cleanup();
    
      return;
    }


    Download("https://github.com/R3uan3/test/files/9544940/test.zip");
```

`CURLCode res` return (CURLE_OK) but it create a file `data.zip` of `0 bytes`, what's wrong?

Comment: You should set [CURLOPT_FAILONERROR](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_FAILONERROR.html) or check the http status of the response otherwise curl could silently ignore errors from the server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## The issue

I checked with

```
curl -I https://github.com/R3uan3/test/files/9544940/test.zip
```

It gets

```
HTTP/2 302
...
location: https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-rep...
```

In other words: this is a redirect and you did not ask libcurl to follow redirects - so you only get that first response stored (which has a zero byte body).

## The fix

You can make libcurl follow the redirect by adding this line to your code:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel, do you know how to input github authorization token in the request?

Comment: that's a totally separate question...